# A probable malfunction in JFrame default close operation

Tags: java, swing

I'm experiencing a few issues with the JFrame's DefaultCloseOperation. I'm using Netbeans. I have set the close operation to custom code in the properties window of JFrame.
Whenever I run this JFrame,the custom code executes automatically.Even if I dont close the frame.The custom code is basically a function:

```
public static int logout(){

   int userconfirm=  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want 
             to Exit?","Please Confirm",YES_NO_OPTION);
   if(userconfirm==0){
       return 1;
   }
   else 
      return 0;
   }
```

I dont know what int value must be returned for closing the frame,I'm just experimenting,so I return a zero or a one.

Comment: Which means you are calling logout() function somewhere where it should not have been.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post [mcve]

Comment: I call it from the same class and somewhat like this: Form.setDefaultCloseOperation(logout());

Comment: `Form.setDefaultCloseOperation(logout());` - that makes no sense. You can only display the JOptionPane in response to some user event. Again you haven't posted your "MCVE", so we can't offer any further help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(userconfirm==0){
```

First of all, don't use magic numbers. People don't know what "0" means. The API provides variables like `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` that you can use. Use the variable provided by the API to make the code more readable.

> Whenever I run this JFrame,the custom code executes automatically.Even if I dont close the frame

You should be using a WindowListener to monitor the closing of the window. The basic logic would be something like:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(...);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter()
{
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
            frame,
            "Are you sure you want to exit the application?",
            "Exit Application",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
});

frame.setVisible( true );
```

Note: there is no need for a method as the closing logic is all handled inside the listener.

See [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for more information and coding ideas.

Comment: It sure is a good option.But is there not a feature in the IDE which will allow me to achieve the same?[Only because I'm doing a minor school 'project '].They seem to hate internal working mods.

Comment: @JeetPatil,  An IDE is just there to help you write the code, compile the code and debug the code. If you want to respond to user events, then you need to write the code yourself. The IDE might help you create a template tor the WindowListener, but you still need to add the logic to the proper event and add the listener to the window. My normal advice is don't use the IDE to generate GUI code because you spend time learning the IDE and not Swing. I just showed in you in a few lines of code how easy this is to implement.